# Discord bot not Assigning roles (C# Discord.net)

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I'm building a bot that is meant to assign a role when the user dms the bot "!Accept" the problem is when I attempt to test this I receive this error

A MessageReceived handler has thrown an unhandled exception.:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Discord.Commands.SocketCommandContext..ctor(DiscordSocketClient client, SocketUserMessage msg)
at UBot_CodeV2.Program.d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\sarah\source\repos\UBot_CodeV2\UBot_CodeV2\Program.cs:line 70
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Discord.EventExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.d__132.MoveNext()
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    [Command("Accept")]
    public async Task Accepted()
    {
            var role = Context.Guild.GetRole(780162818729050114);
        if ((Context.Guild.GetUser(Context.User.Id).Roles.Contains(role))) return;
            await ((SocketGuildUser)Context.User).AddRoleAsync(role);
            await Context.User.SendMessageAsync("Welcome! Your next step is to open a ticket with !ticket open Verification");
        
    }
```

This is the code I have for the task curently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If the user is executing this via DMs the Context.Guild will be null. There is no guild in context as the user is in DMs and not a Guild.

Comment: so would it not be possible to through dms?

Comment: If this a private bot, you can use `Context.Client.GetGuild(guildId)` to get guild first before using .`GetRole`. But if this supposed to be public bot, you need to map the `guild` and `user` first. But things will be more complex after this.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like Context.User at least after setting the guild manually the error is still persisting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the similar code that you're using, and mine is working. Here the result and I put some comment in the code for you to debug. I will explain more after the code.

```
[Command("test")]
public async Task TestAsyync()
{
    var guild = Context.Client.GetGuild(759016895390154754); // Debug if it's not null
    var role = guild.GetRole(776340732075573310); // Debug if it's not null
    var user = Context.Guild.GetUser(Context.User.Id); // Debug if it's not null

    if (!user.Roles.Contains(role))
    {
        await user.AddRoleAsync(role);
        LogUtils.Info("Add role");
    } else
    {
        LogUtils.Info("User already have role");
    }
}
```

Case(s)

- If `guild` is null probably your bot doesn't have access to the guild
- If `role` or `user` is null, there could be issue regarding your bot intents ([Why can't my bot dm users a welcome message? (Discord.net C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065958/why-cant-my-bot-dm-users-a-welcome-message-discord-net-c/65068247#65068247))
- If `await user.AddRoleAsync(role);` return forbidden, you need to set your bot role above the other role

Red square is my bot role, purple one is the role I want to grant

[image: attachment]

I actually just learn today about this role hierarchy ([Discord.NET assigning roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52153990/discord-net-assigning-roles))